# Apache/PHP Won't Start in Ampps

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, ampps

All of the sudden, Apache in Ampps won't start anymore. Of course, I have tried checking port 80, but nothing is listening/running on port 80. Please help, thank you. Also, I have checked the Apache logs and according to the logs everything is fine. But, in the Ampps UI, it says next to Apache, "Stopped."
Here is a part of the logs:

`[Sun Jun 24 07:04:14.190632 2018] [core:notice] [pid 19300:tid 712] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache'
[Sun Jun 24 07:04:14.190632 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 19300:tid 712] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 23216
[Sun Jun 24 07:04:14.910118 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 23216:tid 724] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Jun 24 07:04:27.659321 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21360:tid 680] AH00455: Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0f PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 24 07:04:27.659321 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21360:tid 680] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul  7 2017 11:43:51`

Comment: What part of that log output has the error? It looks like it's running to me.

Comment: It does look like it, but it actually isn't running.

Comment: Then you're going to have to provide more information than a log file that shows that everything looks OK.

Comment: Such as?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I just had to replace all the PHP files with new ones!